# Growth rate of finitely generated nilpotent groups

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, nilpotent-groups, subgroup-growth

Let $N$ be a group and $S$ a finite, symmetric generating set with the identity.

For $n \in \mathbb N$, we let $S^n = \{s_1\dots s_n\mid s_i \in S\}$

We say $N$ has polynomial growth rate if $\exists c,d > 0 $ such that $|S^n| \leq cn^d$

I am asked to show that if $N$ is nilpotent, then the growth rate is indeed polynomial.

After doing some research, I have found some "old" papers proving this result. However, these proofs are quite long and hard to understand, and so I expect there might be an easier way.

However, I have an issue that I don't know how to start.

I think that by nilpotency of $N$ we may assume that $S$ is closed under commutators, since all commutators are eventually the identity, and this would guarantee that $S$ is still finite.

Also we can utilise the fact that the growth rate of a group is actually independent of the generating set, and so if we can bound the growth of this $S^n$, then we'd be done.

I have thought about perhaps trying to manually compute the size of $S^n$, but there seem to be too many unknowns here for me to be able to do this.

I have also thought about perhaps finding a subgroup that has polynomial growth, since I am aware that this is equivalent, but I don't know much about the structure of subgroups of a nilpotent group, so I'm not entirely sure if this would be a helpful approach.

I would appreciate any helpful hint that may point me in the right direction regarding how I should approach this, thank you!

Comment: A finite-index subgroup* . I don't know if this would work, but can't you try to induct on the nilpotency index ? By relating the growth of $E$, $G$ and $N$ in an exact sequence $1\to E\to N\to G\to 1$

Comment: It's a subtle result. It's normal that the proofs are quite elaborated.

Comment: If you don't know where to start (and would like to reach a proof by yourself), I'd suggest to start with the 2-step nilpotent case, then 3-step nilpotent.